# MySQL left join with NULL values

Tags: mysql

I'm certain this has been asked and answered already but don't know how exactly the question should be.

I have two tables

```
ID | name
=========
 1 | foo
 2 | bar
 3 | lou
 4 | sue
```

and a meta table:

```
p_ID | key | value
===================
  1  | poo | 1
  2  | zoo | 'whatever'
  3  | clu | 423
  4  | poo | 1
```

I like to get all entries from the first table which doesn'T have a `poo` value assigned:

```
ID | name
=========
 2 | bar
 3 | lou
```

My approach was

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table AS p 
  LEFT JOIN meta AS m 
    ON m.p_id = p.ID 
 WHERE m.key = 'poo' 
   AND m.value IS NULL
```

but this returns an empty result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to move the `m.key = 'poo'` expression into the ON-clause. Everything that is in the WHERE-clause MUST be present, even in a LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table AS p 
  LEFT 
  JOIN meta AS m 
    ON m.p_id = p.ID 
   AND m.key = 'poo'
 WHERE m.value IS NULL
```

Comment: I knew it was that easy!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should want this;)

```
SELECT *
FROM table AS p
LEFT JOIN meta AS m
ON m.p_id = p.ID
AND m.key = 'poo'
WHERE m.value IS NULL
```

When you use `m.key = 'poo'` in `WHERE` clause, this will be computed as `INNER JOIN`, so you only get records with `m.key = 'poo'`, not all rows in table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INNER JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT *
    FROM `table` T
    INNER JOIN meta M ON M.p_id = T.ID
    WHERE M.key <> 'poo'
```